# Python: Identify the duplicate JSON values and generate an output file with sets of duplicate input rows, one row per set of duplicates

Tags: python, json

I am trying to find duplicated JSON objects in a 30GB jsonlines file.

Given a JSON object A that look like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "cert_index": 691749790,
    "cert_link": "http://ct.googleapis.com/icarus/ct/v1/get-entries?start=691749790&end=691749790",
    "chain": [{...},{...}],
    "leaf_cert": {
      "all_domains": [...],
      "as_der": "MIIFcjCCBFqgAwIBAgISBDD2+d1gP36/+9uUveS...",
      "extensions": {...},
      "fingerprint": "0C:E4:AF:24:F1:AE:B1:09:B0:42:67:CB:F8:FC:B6:AF:1C:07:D6:5B",
      "not_after": 1573738488,
      "not_before": 1565962488,
      "serial_number": "430F6F9DD603F7EBFFBDB94BDE4BBA4EC9A",
      "subject": {...}
    },
    "seen": 1565966152.750253,
    "source": {
      "name": "Google 'Icarus' log",
      "url": "ct.googleapis.com/icarus/"
    },
    "update_type": "PrecertLogEntry"
  },
  "message_type": "certificate_update"
}
```

How can I generate an output file where each row looks like this:

```
{"fingerprint":"0C:E4:AF:24:F1:AE:B1:09:B0:42:67:CB:F8:FC:B6:AF:1C:07:D6:5B", "certificates":[A, B, C]}
```

Here A, B, and C are the full JSON object for each of the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an array with your information. And before adding a new JSON, check if the fingerprint is already in the array. For example:

```
currentFingerprint = myJson['data']['leaf_cert']['fingerprint']
for elem in arrayOfFingerprints:
    if elem['fingerprint'] == currentFingerprint:
        elem['certificates'].append(myJson)
        break
else:
    arrayOfFingerprints.append({'fingerprint': currentFingerprint, 'certificates': [myJson]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you have already read the `file` and created a list of `dict`s.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import json

d = defaultdict(list)
for jobj in file:
    d[jobj['data']['leaf_cert']['fingerprint']].append(jobj)

with open('file.txt', 'w') as out:
    for k,v in d:
        json.dump({"fingerprint":k, "certificates":v})
```

Comment: Would this still work if the file is 30GB? I'm trying to figure out a way to do this in a reasonable amount of time on a single machine.

Comment: Ok, no then. You would need a large fraction of a terrabyte of memory to store everything as python objects.